# IONIC: App module not work with providers

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, provider

I'm using Ionic 2 and my app not work with global providers.

My provider declaration:

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [
       MyService
   ]
})
```

My provider content:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
   ...
}
```

And in my component:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(serviceVariable: MyService) {
        serviceVariable.someMethod();
    }
}
```

My ionic info:
    Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
    Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1

```
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.9
Node Version: v6.2.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

When i try  to use in my application i dont see the provider MyService.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Have imported and declared provider in app.module.ts ??

Comment: it works inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes, i imported and declared ::: import {MyService} from '../providers/my-service'; ::: declarations: [..., MyService]. The contructor dont see the service. Not work!